# Loading time MySQL table taking too long

Tags: javascript, mysql, google-apps-script, google-sheets

how are you?

I have a MySQL database in Google Cloud and I developed a code stored in Google Sheets that calls a table view in a my database.

The table has 22 columns and 153 rows currently.

The issue that I have is that it is taking about 120 secs to load the call from MySQL to Google Sheets using the following code.

Can you please, take a look on the code and tell me if there is a way to load all the rows directly without the need to read column by column and later loading row by row.

As you can tell, in the for cycle, the 22 columns are read and pushed to an array (arr) that is pushed to another array (values) which is the one that is going to be finally loaded. This is taking processing time and taking almost 2 mins to upload the 153 rows. When I have 1000 rows this is not going to be feasible to use.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

---

```
function readFromTable2() {

  var conn = Jdbc.getCloudSqlConnection(dbUrl, user, userPwd);
   var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var start = new Date();
  var stmt = conn.createStatement();
  stmt.setMaxRows(1000);
  var results = stmt.executeQuery('SELECT * FROM Employeesview');
  var metaData = results.getMetaData();
  var numCols = results.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
  var arr = []; 
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet3');
  var rangotop = sheet.getRange('A1')
var values = [];
  while (results.next()) {
    arr = [];
    for (var col = 0; col < numCols; col++) {
      arr.push(results.getString(col + 1));
    }
     values.push(arr)
  }

  results.close();
  stmt.close();
  var rows = values.length;
  rangotop.offset(1,0,rows,numCols).setValues(values);

var end = new Date();
   var Timeelapsed = (end - start)/1000;
  ui.alert(Timeelapsed);
}
```

---

I made the code below based on the suggestions given:

But when I run it, I get the following times:

- 4.38 secs
- 27.84 secs
  -4.101 secs
  -2.86 secs
  115.11 secs

As you can tell the times goes from 2.8 secs up to 115 secs per run. If is the same code that I run several times, why I am getting a wide range of time. My internet is currently ping 9ms / down 96 M / Up 5 M.
Thanks for your help

```
function testotro() {

  var conn = Jdbc.getCloudSqlConnection(dbUrl, user, userPwd);
  var smt = conn.createStatement();
  var start = new Date();
  var rs = smt.executeQuery('SELECT *  FROM Employeesview');
  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var cell = doc.getRange('a1');
  var row = 0;
  var getCount = rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
  for (var i = 0; i < getCount; i++) {
    cell.offset(row, i).setValue(rs.getMetaData().getColumnName(i + 1));
  }
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('testotro');
  var values = [];
  while (rs.next()) {
    var L2s = [];
    L2s.push(rs.getString(1), rs.getString(2), rs.getString(3), rs.getString(4), rs.getString(5), rs.getString(6), rs.getString(7), rs.getString(8), rs.getString(9), rs.getString(10),
      rs.getString(11), rs.getString(12), rs.getString(13), rs.getString(14), rs.getString(15), rs.getString(16), rs.getString(17), rs.getString(18), rs.getString(19), rs.getString(20), rs.getString(21));
    values.push(L2s)
  }
  cell.offset(1, 0, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
  rs.close();
  smt.close();
  conn.close();
  var end = new Date();
  Logger.log('Time elapsed: %sms', (end - start) / 1000);

}
```

Comment: Which statement is the bottleneck?

Comment: It's seems to be well written to me.  If you're watching it from the script editor then you might prefer to use the Logger rather than the alert but I assume that you realize that.  Personally I've found the JDBC to be rather slow so I wouldn't be alarmed by the two minutes.

Comment: If speed is a priority for you then Apps Script's JDBC service is far from ideal. You can try creating a GCP Cloud Function that can query the database and update a sheet, and either expose it as an HTTP endpoint or, if you want it to be asynchronous, hook it up to Cloud Pubsub. Then invoke the Cloud Function from Apps Script (by directly hitting the endpoint or publishing a message to a PubSub topic). Not trivial to implement but doable.

Comment: The bottle neck is that is lasting 1 min to read all the 22 columns from the table, and if I have 150 records, last more than 2 mins. If when I have 1000 records it would last very long. So I need a code that help me with the speed of retrieving data. Kind regards

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, I get all columns together, no need for that FOR LOOP

```
function getL2s() {
  var L2s = [];
  try {
    var fullConnectionString = 'jdbc:' + DB_TYPE + '://' + HOST + ':' + PORT;
    var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(fullConnectionString, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
    var stmt = conn.createStatement();
    stmt.execute('USE ' + DATABASE);
    var query = "SELECT * FROM L2s WHERE !IsDeleted ORDER BY TeamTL";
    var rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

    while (rs.next()) {
      L2s.push([rs.getString(1), rs.getString(2), rs.getString(3), rs.getString(4), rs.getString(5)]);
    }
    rs.close();
    stmt.close();
  } catch (e) {
        console.log(e, e.lineNumber);
        //Browser.msgBox(e);
  }

  return L2s;
}
```

The above is from one of my projects that accesses MySQL

I write the array to my sheet using this script

```
  // write L2s array to L2s tab, not needed but might be useful for debugging
  writeDataToSheet(L2s, "L2s");
```

Which is essentially a call to setValues

```
function goToSheet(sheetName) {
    ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName(sheetName));
}

// Writes a 2D array of data to sheet
function writeDataToSheet(data, sheetName) {
  goToSheet(sheetName);
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  // Leave header row, assume no more than 26 columns and use "Z" for last column
  var range = sheet.getRange("A2:Z");
  range.clear();
  // write date to active sheet starting at the 2nd row
  sheet.getRange(2, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
  return sheet.getName();
}
```

Comment: This pattern is using the exact same number of `results.next()` and `results.getString()` calls, so if the performance bottleneck is with those calls, it will not be faster than the pattern shown in the question.

Comment: Perhaps, but using far less Pushes, no FOR LOOP and no temp array so I would wager it would be faster. Anyway, I answered the question on how to do all columns w/o going column by column

Comment: Milliseconds can add up, for each row having to loop thru all columns not to mention the array overhead. I will take every ms I can save :-)

Comment: Negative and I am not sure why we are debating this, "Can you please, take a look on the code and tell me if there is a way to load all the rows directly without the need to read column by column and later loading row by row." Again, I provided the solution they asked for, Please cease and desist.

Comment: Hi, thanks. Is there a way to transfer the L2s array to the cells in google sheet?

Comment: You are welcome. Basically it is just a call to setValues. I updated my script to show how I handle

Comment: The code provided above reduced from 120 secs to 30 secs aprox. But, using a BigQuery request the time to retrieve exactly the same data is 1.5 secs. So, how can I reduce my time from 30 secs to 5 secs the max? Any suggestions? I need to use MySQL not BigQuery, that is why I need to move my data. Thanks for your help

Comment: Hi JohnA. I really highly appreciated your help. Your code help me a lot, but it is not scalable for the fact that if I add 1000 records time will be still high. Is there a way or a code to reduce to 5 secs or less?